# c # winform mysql data display

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, datagridview

through C # I am creating a program that manages ambulances, I am trying to create a list with the events and active missions, this data must be taken from a mysql database, I have tried to see many "tutorials", but none explained what I needed, how do you think I can do something like this?

[image: image here]

in addition to displaying the data, if I click twice it should open the event or mission to me depending on where I click, (the icons are also buttons that should only be visible if there is a data)

**just a tip! I'm not asking you to write the code for me!!!**

**EDIT:**
I managed to get the data from mysql, that you know is it possible to place the data in specific columns?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are basically asking us to either design, or design and write code from a Specification. 
That is not what StackOverflow is for, we help each other fix code related issues we are having, we dont write code for you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to guide you through such unspecific question, but I'll try some hints.

1. You said you have data from MySQL
2. Fill a `DataTable` (another way is to use `BindingSource`)
3. Assign `DataTable` as a `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` grid.
4. You can edit columns in the `DataGridView` using UI in VS, or you can do it programatically. First is easier, just note that if you at any stage provide Nothing as a data source, you'll loose column headers.
5. For event fired on `DataGridViewRow`, click on the grid in Designer, click on events in the Properties pane, find `DatagridviewRow_DoubleClick` and double click the line, to create associated method
6. FIll in the code into the even method. Use `DataGridView.SelectedRows(0)` to get selected row and it's index. If you want to "open it" create a modal dialog or what you want for displaying the content.